# How to write function in bash for reuse shell commands inside using osascript?

Tags: bash, function, shell, terminal, osascript

I want to get rid of duplicates, but get the errors:
`178:186: syntax error: A “"” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)`
`133:134: syntax error: Expected expression but found unknown token. (-2741)`

```
execute_commands() {
local command = "$1"
osascript <<EOF
    tell application "iTerm" to \
        tell the last session of current tab of current window to \
        write text $command
EOF
}

# function call
execute_commands "cd \"$PROJECT_PATH\"/frontend && npm run dev"
```

I tried to fix it in different ways, nothing works.

Comment: Variable assignments don't have spaces around `=`.

Comment: `write text` needs its argument in quotes.

Comment: And if the argument contains quotes or backslashes, they'll need to be escaped.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! All your comments help to solve the problem